# Is it possible to create a function using tf.GradientTape() that can produce Second Order, Third Order or nth Order Gradients?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, tensorflow2.0, calculus

I have been trying to implement a function that can output the nth Order Differential of a function using GradientTape. For example:

If the function is y = x^2 * sin(x) and x=7 and n=8.

[image: y = x^2 * sin(x)]

Then the first-order differential is dy/dx and the second-order differential is d2y/dx2. The function would return d*n*y/d*n*x.

I tried to implement something below but it didn't work because `tf.GradientTape()` needs to track the equation that needs to be differentiated.

```py
def function(x):
  return (x**2) * tf.math.sin(x)

def gradient_by_order(function,x,n):
  
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = function(x)
  
  d = tape.gradient(y,x)
 
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    for i in range(n):
      d = tape.gradient(d,x)

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=5.)
gradient_by_order(function,x,10)
```

Is there a way to create a working function using recursion or loops or any other method?
Thank you very much :).

Edit: I know that you can get the nth order derivate by nesting `with tf.GradientTape() as tape` like how it is presented in Susmit Agrawal's answer below. I am just curious to know if there is a way to program a function that can output the nth order derivative (given that such a derivative exists) because I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `GradientTape`s for nth order differentiation. The level of nesting is the order of the derivative.

Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(X_VAL)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
    tape1.watch(x)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        tape2.watch(x)
        y = (x**2)*tf.sin(x)
    
    # dy/dx
    first_order = tape2.gradient(y, x)

# d2y/dx2 = (d/dx)(dy/dx) = (d/dx)(first_order)
second_order = tape2.gradient(first_order, x)
```

Further reference:
[Official documentation on GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape?version=nightly)

Of course, if `x` is an instance of a `tf.Variable`, you don't need to `watch` it explicitly. I leave the experimentation with loops/recursion up to you.